# loading php variable from header-function

Tags: php, html, variables, header

i would like to make folders for its own languages.

as an example i have the file `foo.php`. that file has a english version and a dutch version also.

therefor i created the directories `/english/foo.php` and `/dutch/foo.php` both files in that directories will be exactly the same as in the root folder.

in the root folder `root/foo.php` i load a variable `$var` that comes from an other file and directory that is called `root/scripts/bar.php`

in the file `root/scripts/bar.php` i do use a header function:

```
if ($pref_language == 'zu'){
    $header = 'english'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
    $var = "xyz";  
}

header ("location: $header");
```

the problem is that when i will open `root/foo.php` the header function works as it should be but `$var` wont be initialised on that headered direction. when i will open source code there is nothing for

```
<?php echo $var;?>
```

but when looking at the source code without headering the variable will be loaded.

so this is a little bit strange to me. if there is someone who could help me out i really appreciate.

thanks alot.

Comment: I hope you didn't put business logic on `foo.php`

Comment: Did you put business/application  logic on `foo.php`?

Comment: what do you mean with business logic?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic

Comment: no i dont have any business logic on that.

Answer (score 0):

Using `header("location: $header");` redirects the browser to `$header`, this is not what you want.

You could `include($header);` (documented [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or more probably `require` documented [here](https://www.php.net/require)) which would then allow the file in `$header` to use the variables defined.

What seems like you really want to do is internationalization, and there are good tools to do that in PHP such as Twig ([here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)) or Smarty ([here](http://www.smarty.net/))

Answer (score 0):

Your best best might be to utilize rewrite rules in your webserver to direct URL requests for certain languages to a parameter that can be used by the php file.  An example in Apache might look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(english|dutch)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The would for example cause requests to `/english/foo.php` to be passed to `/foo.php?lang=english` for processing.

You could then look at `$_GET['lang']` to determine which localization to use.

This eliminates the need to do any browser redirects, and gives you a nice way to dynamically prepend the `$_GET['lang']` value to all links within your site to give the appearance to teh end user that they are completely within the English site (`/english/*`) or the Dutch site (`/dutch/*`).

Comment: hello, i use http_accept_language to get the information that i need. so using htaccess is not an option for me.